# SQL in Flask/Python: Distinct values?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a normalised database and I've created a query to select Pokemon's type.

```
SELECT pokedata.name, poketypes.type
FROM pokedata
LEFT JOIN poketypes
ON pokedata.pokeID = poketypes.pokeID
```

Output

```
+-----------+--------+
|   Name    |  Type  |
+-----------+--------+
| Bulbasaur | grass  |
| Bulbasaur | poison |
| Ivysaur   | grass  |
| Ivysaur   | poison |
| Venusaur  | grass  |
| Venusaur  | poison |
+-----------+--------+
```

However, in Flask or Python, I am not sure how to take this query and use it without repeating the name value.

Here is what I have currently:

pokemon.py

```
pokemon = conn.execute("SELECT p.name, poketypes.type FROM pokedata AS p LEFT JOIN poketypes ON p.pokeID = poketypes.pokeID")
return render_template('index.html', pokemon=pokemon)
```

index.html

```
      {% for row in pokemon %}  
       {{ row['name'] }} has types {{ row['type'] }} 
      {% endfor %}

Output
Bulbasaur has types grass 
Bulbasaur has types poison
```

Here is what I am hoping to output (I assume I need a loop, but I'm not sure how to implement it)

```
Bulbasaur has types grass, poison
Ivysaur has types grass, poison
```

(I wasn't sure what title would make sense - feel free to suggest a better title!)

Comment: Do `groupby` on the results in the query

Answer (score 1):

Use defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
rows=[['Bulbasaur','grass'],
['Bulbasaur','poison '],
['Ivysaur','grass']
]
d=defaultdict(list)
for row in rows:
    d[row[0]].append(row[1])

for k,v in d.items()    :
    print(f"{k} has types {', '.join(v)} ")
```

> Bulbasaur has types grass, poison
>
> Ivysaur has types grass

Answer (score 0):

`group_concat()` is your friend:

```
SELECT pokedata.name, group_concat(poketypes.type, ', ') AS types
FROM pokedata
LEFT JOIN poketypes ON pokedata.pokeID = poketypes.pokeID
GROUP BY pokedata.name
ORDER BY pokedata.name;
```

gives

```
name        types       
----------  -------------
Bulbasaur   grass, poison
Ivysaur     grass, poison
Venusaur    grass, poison
```

Comment: I never knew about group_concat, that's awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts on this approach? Is there anything 'wrong' with it per-se? (It works... after much searching about why I needed to convert the objects to lists).

I guess two SQL queries isn't ideal?

```
pokemonDetails = conn.execute("SELECT pokedata.pokeID, pokedata.name FROM pokedata")
pokemonDetails = list(pokemonDetails)

pokemonTypes = conn.execute("SELECT pokedata.pokeID, poketypes.type FROM pokedata LEFT JOIN poketypes ON pokedata.pokeID = poketypes.pokeID")
pokemonTypes = list(pokemonTypes)


 {% for row in pokemonDetails %}
    {{ row['name'] }}
    {% for type in pokemonTypes if row['pokeID'] == type['pokeID'] %}
        {{ type['type'] }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```